# Angular ng build vs. ng serve performance

Tags: angular, angular-cli

If `ng serve` is working fine, why should we go for the `ng build` except size issues, is there any specific reason ?

I know that `ng build` writes generated build artifacts to the output folder but I want to know if there is any performance difference.

Comment: The dev server is simply *not* designed for production use.

Answer (score 2):

The `ng build` command is intentionally for building the apps and deploying the build artifacts.

The `ng serve` command is intentionally for fast, local and iterative developments and also for builds, watches and serves the application from a local CLI development server.
Also, if you running the angular app using `ng serve` and if you make any changes to your app, the changes are captured and reflected instantaneously on the UI. This avoids starting and stopping the server again and again.

Both commands `ng build` and `ng serve` will clear the output folder before they build the project.

The main difference is – The `ng build` command writes generated build artifacts to the output folder and the `ng serve` command does not. By default, the output folder is - dist/.

Also the `ng serve` builds artifacts from memory instead for a faster development experience.
The `ng build` command generates output files just once and does not serve them.

The `ng build --watch` command will regenerate output files when source files change. This `--watch` flag is useful if you're building during development and are automatically re-deploying changes to another server.

Refer this [link](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) for more information on Angular apps deployment.

**conclusion**

```
`ng serve`
```

does not write build and it builds artifacts from memory instead for a faster development experience.

```
`ng build`
```

writes generated build artifacts to the output folder (by default is -dist/).