# Should I use ng build or ng serve for nginx?

Tags: angular, nginx

I have searched fruitlessly for over an hour for this doubt. I have got some answers [Angular ng build vs. ng serve performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59045926/angular-ng-build-vs-ng-serve-performance), but it doesn't indicate which is better and why?

So my question is what is better, starting a server with `ng serve --prod` and then using nginx to reverse proxy, or `ng build --prod` and then hosting it using nginx server.

Comment: what should I do then?

Comment: Build the application using `ng build`, copy the files to a web server. https://angular.io/guide/deployment#basic-deployment-to-a-remote-server

Comment: isn't nginx also a web server

Answer (score 0):

"ng serve" launches the application in a local environment, which is practical during development phases.

"ng serve --prod" will allow you to build a production build and run it on a local environment. The purpose is to simulate a production build in the local development environment.

**"ng serve" does not have to be used to run a production environment**.

"ng build" only create a generated build, not to execute it. If we add the argument "--prod" to the command, we've got a build ready for production.

To deploy your application into production, you need to run "ng build --prod" and then place the generated build on a web server. This will make your application available for Client Side Rendering.

However, if you need your web application to be referenced on the web (for example), it is also possible to build an Angular application for Server Side Rendering. Angular has a solution called [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) that allows you to do this.

I suggest you to consult the official documentation of Angular for more details.

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question, I am saying which is a better way and why, i.e should I host my built code on nginx or run an individual angular server and then reverse proxy.

Comment: You have two choices for production: SSR (Server Side Rendering) or CSR (Client Side Rendering).
In terms of performance, an SSR application will run faster than a CSR application.
An SSR application will also be indexable by web crawlers, while a CSR will not.

But the SSR application will be more complicated to set up and maintain.